# Why is A-Frame WebVR not working the same on mobile as desktop?

Tags: ios, aframe, webvr, 360-virtual-reality, glitch-framework

we are using an A-Frame WebVR program created in Glitch and it works great on desktop in VR mode. However, when we try and use it on a mobile device, the 360 scene we created is slanted. Also on a desktop you can use your mouse to move around the scene, but on iPhone you can use your finger to move around the scene but only in one plane, as in we can only move from side to side and nothing else. I am not a coder! I am just using a program created by my predecessor. Any help would be SOOO appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDa8c.png)

Answer (score 0):

Made a [remix](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/clackamas-2?path=index.html%3A50%3A20), and updated the website to the current `a-frame` version which is `1.2.0` (instead of `0.6.1`) and it already looks like it fixed the problem ([link](https://clackamas-2.glitch.me/)).

Broke the animations though, You'll need to use the [`animation`](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#sidebar) component instead of the `<a-animation>` (which now are deprecated).

---

> I am not a coder!

There are 1000+ lines of stuff there, You better be prepared to get your hands dirty :P